# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on UIView in the navigationBar titleView?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add `tapGesture` on `navigationBar` `titleView` but not getting any event. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
 let titleView = UIView()
 titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60)
 titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

 let profileImageView = UIImageView()
 profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
 profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
 profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
 profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: user.image)
 titleView.addSubview(profileImageView)
 profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
 profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
 profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

 let nameLabel = UILabel()
 nameLabel.text = user.name
 nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)
 titleView.addSubview(nameLabel)
 nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
 nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
 nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

 self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
 titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatTableViewController)))
```

Comment: show your showChatTableViewController function

Comment: add `titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`. By default it true but if it's not working in your case then try to set `true`

Make sure to debug your code and check that after adding titleView are you able to print out `self.navigationItem.titleView` ?

```
let titleView = UIView()
titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60)
titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatTableViewController)))

@objc func showChatTableViewController() {
    print("tapped")
}
```